# Transform a Data Frame Wide to Long and Apply a Map (Python 3.5.1 Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently writing a bunch of table transformation statements in Postgres, which I want to write a function for in Python to reduce the amount of repeated code I have. Suppose I have a table which I load into Pandas that looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'state' : ['NJ', 'NJ', 'NY', 'NY'],
      'county' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'],
      'population' : [100, 200, 300, 400],
      'other' : [11, 12, 13, 14],
      'row_number': [1, 2, 3, 4]
     }


   county   other   population  row_number  state
0   AAA      11         100         1       NJ
1   BBB      12         200         2       NJ
2   CCC      13         300         3       NY
3   DDD      14         400         4       NY
```

I want to keep the state and county columns. The `other` and `population` field represents actual data fields. In the end I want to map these values into Excel spreadsheet columns and rows. The field `row_number` represents the row number corresponding to the state and county.

Now suppose I have a dictionary that has the "mapping" between the two data fields to columns. Let's say it looks like

```
column_mapping = {'other': 'A',
                  'population': 'B'
                 }
```

I want to produce a Data Frame that looks like:

```
   county   state         value         row 
0   AAA       NJ          11            A1         
1   AAA       NJ          100           B1
2   BBB       NJ          12            A2
3   BBB       NJ          200           B2          
4   CCC       NY          13            A3     
5   CCC       NY          300           B3     
6   DDD       NY          14            A4
7   DDD       NY          400           B4
```

Of secondary importance, I'm trying to do this in the most general way possible because I want to pass several different tables into this function with similar structure, but possibly different column names (`state`, `county`, and `row_number` will always be the same but the actual data fields might be different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for reshaping, then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) column `variable`, combine columns with casting integer column to string by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) unnecessary columns:

```
column_mapping = {'other': 'A',
                  'population': 'B'
                 }

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['county','state', 'row_number'], 
                 value_vars=['other', 'population']) 

df['variable'] = df['variable'].map(column_mapping)
df['row'] = df['variable'] + df['row_number'].astype(str)

df = df.drop(['variable','row_number'], axis=1) 

#if you need sort by county column with reset index
 df = df.sort_values('county').reset_index(drop=True)
print df
  county state  value row
0    AAA    NJ     11  A1
1    AAA    NJ    100  B1
2    BBB    NJ     12  A2
3    BBB    NJ    200  B2
4    CCC    NY     13  A3
5    CCC    NY    300  B3
6    DDD    NY     14  A4
7    DDD    NY    400  B4
```

EDIT:

If you need use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) more general, omit `value_vars`:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['county','state', 'row_number']) 
df['variable'] = df['variable'].map(column_mapping)
df['row'] = df['variable'] + df['row_number'].astype(str)
df = df.drop(['variable','row_number'], axis=1) 
df = df.sort_values('county').reset_index(drop=True)
print df
  county state  value row
0    AAA    NJ     11  A1
1    AAA    NJ    100  B1
2    BBB    NJ     12  A2
3    BBB    NJ    200  B2
4    CCC    NY     13  A3
5    CCC    NY    300  B3
6    DDD    NY     14  A4
7    DDD    NY    400  B4
```

Comment: Thanks! This mostly works for me, but I am getting a really weird error. I am using `pd.read_sql` to run a query and return a DataFrame. When I do this, I get an error:     `frame = frame.ix[:, id_vars + value_vars]`
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ix'`. But when I use `pd.read_sql_table` directly, I don't get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Very hard question. Are `DataFrames` same using `pd.read_sql` and `pd.read_sql_table` ? Are `indexes` same? Or one contain `Multiindex` and other  `index`?

Comment: After many hours, I realize I had an extra comma hanging out in the middle of my code =[[[[